# Oracle Merge/Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to see if there is an existing 'IMPORTID' in a table consisting of two columns: 'IMPORTID','STEP'. If there is, increment the record's STEP column by 1.

I've just tested using hardcoded values and there are no rows in the table currently. I'm expecting the following SQL to insert an entry but nothing is happening.

```
MERGE into TOSTEP t
USING
    (SELECT 'Test' IMPORTID, 1 STEP FROM TOSTEP) s
ON
    (s.IMPORTID = t.IMPORTID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   update set t.STEP = s.STEP +1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    insert (IMPORTID,STEP)
    values ('Test',1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are merging an empty table with itself..meaning there is no data selected in `using` clause. Change `(SELECT 'Test' IMPORTID, 1 STEP FROM TOSTEP) s` into `(SELECT 'Test' IMPORTID, 1 STEP FROM DUAL) s` and it should work

FULL CODE:

```
MERGE into TOSTEP t
USING
    (SELECT 'Test' IMPORTID, 1 STEP FROM DUAL) s
ON
    (s.IMPORTID = t.IMPORTID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   update set t.STEP = s.STEP +1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    insert (IMPORTID,STEP)
    values (s.IMPORTID, s.STEP);
```